# why am i getting error -Single '}' encountered in format string

Tags: python

I am writing some code to see print out a list of words that I can make with the string of letters 'myLetters', but for some reason my formatting wont work. It is supposed to come out as a list of words with as many spaces between it and the value as the length of myLetters + 4

```
def scrabbleWords(myLetters):
        letterPoints = {'a':1,'b':3,'c':3,'d':2, 'e':1,'f':4,'g':2,'h':4,\
    'i':1,'j':8,'k':5,'l':1,'m':3,'n':1,'o':1,'p':3,'q':10,'r':1,'s':1,\
    't':1,'u':1,'v':4,'w':4,'x':8,'y':4}
        wordList = createWordList('wordlist.txt')
        myWords = []
        for myWord in wordList:
            x = canWeMakeIt(myWord,myLetters)
            if x == True:
                myWords.append(myWord)


        pointWordList = []
        for myWord in myWords:
            t = getWordPoints(myWord,letterPoints)
            pointWordList.append((t,myWord))
        pointWordList.sort(reverse=True)


        lenx = str(len(myLetters)+4)
        for pointValue, myWord in pointWordList:
            x = '{:'+lenx+'}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue)
            print(x)
```

Comment: please provide the actual error you are recieving, and also you input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

```
'{:'+lenx+'}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue)
```

interprets as

```
'{:'     +     lenx     +     '}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue)
```

Change it to:

```
'{1:{0}}{2}'.format(lenx, myWord, pointValue)
```

**EDIT**: don't forget to change `lenx` to an integer (or don't convert it to string at all):

```
lenx = len(myLetters) + 4
```

Comment: `'{1:{0}}{2}'.format("foo","bar",3)` gives me `ValueError: Invalid conversion specification`

Comment: `lenx = str(len(myLetters)+4)`?

Comment: I would, if it was my question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `'{:'+lenx+'}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue)` expression which tries to add `lenx+'}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue)` to the sum `'{:'+lenx`.

This would do what I think you want and be a little more readable in my opinion:

```
x = '{:{width}}{}'.format(myWord, pointValue, width=lenx)
```

**EDIT**: Plus this works whether `lenx` is an integer or string value.

Answer (score 0):

The "Single '}' encountered in format string" error is due to the fact that we are looking at a bit of code that does not work without some bracketing.

You wrote

```
'{:'+lenx+'}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue)
```

but probably meant

```
('{:'+lenx+'}{}').format(myWord,pointValue)
```

whereas python's interpretation is:

```
'{:'+lenx+('}{}'.format(myWord,pointValue))
```